# why .net core self contained app depends on runtimeconfig.dev.json

Tags: .net-core, self-contained

I'm using .net core to build a self contained application accroding to following guide:
1. create a new .net core Console app:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows
2. follow these step to publish application with self-contained:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli

After publish the application, I do run the application correctly, but when I remove file myApp1.runtimeconfig.dev.json, my application is can not startup again.
The error message:

---

Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (myApp1.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtime.win-x86.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '2.0.0'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x86/lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll'

---

Answer (score 2):

The `runtimeconfig.json` file is required for .NET Core applications. `runtime.config.json` file that specifies the shared runtime that the application expects, as well as other configuration options for the runtime (for example, garbage collection type), it is one of the `dotnet publish` output which is ready for deployment to a hosting system for execution.

Comment: But, how to build a totally self contained application which doesn't depends on the runtime ?

Comment: Your app is self-contained, the runtime is just in the publish folder. You can see this link: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx